# Does an MS Teams bot require an Azure AI Bot registration?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am developing a notification bot for MS Teams (based on [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-notificationbot?source=recommendations&tabs=vscode)). As in the tutorial, I used the Visual Studio Code "Teams Toolkit" to generate the base code for the application, and then modified the code according to my needs. I tested my app locally (using the Teams Toolkit debug function) and it works as intended. Now, I need to deploy the application somewhere. I know it can be hosted in Azure, which is what the linked tutorial suggests. My question is as follows:

> If I decide **not** to host my app (bot) on Azure, do I still need to register my app with the Azure AI Bot service in order for it to work (i.e. still connect and send messages to Teams)? What I mean is the process described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned).

***Note**: The first paragraph almost suggests I don't need to, but I have not found a single resource online that demonstrates setting up a Teams bot without at some point registering the bot on Azure as described.*

---

I have tried looking at various documentation and sample apps to see if there is ever a time when a Teams bot was deployed without requiring an Azure AI Bot service registration. E.g. following the instructions in the README for this sample app (c.f. step 2 in the "Setup" section, asks for bot registration as I have linked): https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-proactive-messaging/csharp/README.md

Comment: Hello @ccroth - As an alternative you can use Graph API's for sending message to Teams chat or channels: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I was trying with Graph API and it seems that it won't work for my use case. I have another application which I need to programmatically send messages into a Teams chat, and the Application type permission which allows this is "Teamwork.Migrate.All". That permission does not allow you to POST directly to a chat. You need to go through a whole import process as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams.

Delegated permission types won't work because because my other app won't allow user sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we don't have any way (Except Migration mode) for posting messages with application permissions. Only option to send a message to channel using Graph API would be using delegated permission.

Please use [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots?view=msteams-client-js-latest) / [Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors?view=msteams-client-js-latest) to send messages.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without using Azure Bot registration ?